# Writing file from batch not working

Tags: batch-file

I am using this code in bat file to write a file. i set the file path in the  %statusfile%, my code not write file neither in if part nor else part

> ```
> if %Counter% equ %SuccessCounter% (  
> echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,True >> %statusfile%  
> ) else (
> set partUpload_flag=1    
> echo List.csv,%Counter%,%SuccessCounter%,%date% %time%,False >>%statusfile%
> ```
>
> )

this is the code where i'm getting counter, i try printing the counter , getting the line count correct only. also i'm getting first line in the file.

> ```
> set statusfile=%rootpath%Input\Status.csv 
> echo FileName,TotalLines,processedLines ,DateTime,status > %statusfile% 
> set /a Counter =0 FOR /F "DELIMS=, TOKENS=1,2" %%p IN ( %rootpath%extras\Input.csv) Do               
> ( set "line=%%a" set "line="!line:,=","!"" 
> set /a Counter +=1 )
> ```

Also one more thing, the condition worked fine for me before i add some more lines to them. once after adding the more lines this stop working, even after removing them it is not working .. the added lines are as below. i added this in the else part.

> ```
> if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 (
>  set success_flag=0
>  set Attachment= %Attachment% -attach %rootpath%extras\error.csv
>  echo %date%%time% ERROR:Error found in records : %ErrorCounter% lines >> %logpath%
> )
> ```

How to fix the issue, as i'm new cant find the way to debug.

Comment: shove some print/echo statements around and in the blocks to make sure that it's working correctly

Comment: Hi 

this is the code where i'm getting counter, i try printing the counter , getting the line count correct only. also i'm getting first line in the file.

>     set statusfile=%rootpath%Input\Status.csv
    echo FileName,TotalLines,processedLines ,DateTime,status > %statusfile%
    set /a Counter =0
    FOR /F "DELIMS=, TOKENS=1,2" %%p IN ( %rootpath%extras\Input.csv) Do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "line="!line:,=","!""
    set /a Counter +=1 
    )

Comment: Also one more thing, the condition worked fine for me before i add some more lines to them. once after adding the more lines this stop working, even after removing them it is not working .. the added lines are as below. i added this in the else part. 
>     if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 (
     set success_flag=0
     set Attachment= %Attachment% -attach %rootpath%extras\error.csv
     echo %date%%time% ERROR:Error found in records : %ErrorCounter% lines >> %logpath%
    )

Comment: can you edit your question with all of that in there?

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer below

Comment: ya , will check and update..

Answer (score 1):

Just ran the code exactly as-is except for stubbing the unknown variables:

```
set counter=1
set successcounter=1
set statusfile=output.txt
```

Ran just fine. Can you post up where you set the variables for counter, successcounter and statusfile? I highly suspect you may be having issues setting variables in a way that batch files read.

P.S. also changed

```
successcounter=2
```

to see "False", behaved as expected, so the syntax is not a problem.

Comment: Also one more thing, the condition worked fine for me before i add some more lines to them. once after adding the more lines this stop working, even after removing them it is not working .. the added lines are as below. i added this in the else part.                       " if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 (
     set success_flag=0
     set Attachment= %Attachment% -attach %rootpath%extras\error.csv
     echo %date%%time% ERROR:Error found in records : %ErrorCounter% lines >> %logpath%
    )"

Comment: Where are you getting this %rootpath% variable from? Just making sure that %rootpath% has this format 'code' <drive letter><optional folder><ends with \>

Comment: Mainly, I'm concerned about the %rootpath%input\status.csv structure. Once again, %rootpath% actual string value must end with a \ to be a valid location unless you actually have a folder named \%rootpath%input\  . Also, if the folder does not already exist, then you will fail with the  ' > %foldername%\filename.txt '

Comment: SET rootpath=%~dp0
set rootpath=%rootpath:~0,-4% >>  i read the line count from the file in path and print it. it shows correct count. can u check my edited qusestion for the added code.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like it's not hitting the if condition**, can you post the whole block?  Here are the lines that i'm trying and it's still working for me (i tried both true and false statements):

```
if 1 equ 1 (
echo abc,123,%date%,%time%,true >>true.txt
) else (
echo abc,123,%date%,%time%,false >>false.txt

)
```

**EDIT:** Seems like that problem is how you're setting the variables.  You need to put the `=` right next to the var (unless you're intending to use the var with a space) example `set /a Counter+=1`.  Like so:

```
set statusfile=%rootpath%Input\Status.csv 
echo FileName,TotalLines,processedLines ,DateTime,status > %statusfile% 
set /a Counter=0
FOR /F "DELIMS=, TOKENS=1,2" %%p IN ( %rootpath%extras\Input.csv) Do (
    set "line=%%a" 
    set "line="!line:,=","!"" 
    set /a Counter+=1
)
```

If you don't change that then you need to use the variable with the space, like so: `if %Counter % equ %SuccessCounter%`

Comment: Also one more thing, the condition worked fine for me before i add some more lines to them. once after adding the more lines this stop working, even after removing them it is not working .. the added lines are as below. i added this in the else part.                       " if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 (
     set success_flag=0
     set Attachment= %Attachment% -attach %rootpath%extras\error.csv
     echo %date%%time% ERROR:Error found in records : %ErrorCounter% lines >> %logpath%
    )"

Comment: hi alex, no this is not working even without space.. is any thing wrong in the if %ErrorCounter% gtr 1 ( code part.

Comment: That block looks ok, unless you have some other statement that read the success status since you're setting the success_flag to 0 `set success_flag=0`